# How to get Utxos from emulation wallet

Tags: plutus

I'm doing integration tests with Emulation
As far as I understand under emulation wallets have initial funds.

Example:

```
test :: IO ()
test = runEmulatorTraceIO $ do
    let 
        w1 = knownWallet 1
        walletAddress = mockWalletAddress w1
        # how to get utxos for walletAddress under emulator ????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helper function can help you. It returns the list of **TxOutRef** and **TxOut** owned by an address.

```
import Control.Lens
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Ledger 
import Ledger.Index
import Plutus.Trace.Emulator qualified as Trace

getUtxos :: Address -> Trace.EmulatorTrace [(TxOutRef, TxOut)]
getUtxos addr = do
    state <- Trace.chainState
    let utxoIndex = getIndex $ state ^. Trace.index 
        utxos     =  [(oref, o) | (oref, o) <- Map.toList utxoIndex, txOutAddress o == addr]
    pure utxos
```

Comment: Oh. Really many thanks ! I'll check

Comment: @ViktorYasterbov, does it work?

Comment: Yeah. Great. Everything is fine. Thank you for help. you gave me good hint eventually how to process things under Emulator. I did the same for getting values etc